# MotionScene error. Motion Editor cannot be used

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, androidx, android-motionlayout

**I am using latest version of motion layout in android and getting following error. I searched couple of answers like delete .idea folder/.build folder/clean project/ invalidate cache and restart. but seems to not work. I am using Android 4.0.1 version in mac. Any idea why it could be.**

```
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-rc1'
```

[image]

Comment: I forced same problem, and moreover if we downgrade to previous beta versions, I can only have the animation  in Motion Editor but not in output.

Answer (score 0):

I tried toggling between versions of library like by refering https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/constraintlayout

```
androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta8

androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta7

androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta6

androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta5
```

In my case **beta7** seems to work. In between, if i am doing something wrong, correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta6' instead of implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-rc1' or other beta version